# Cleaner Dockerfile for continuumio/miniconda3 environment?

Tags: python, docker, conda, quart, hypercorn

I have a Python3.9 / Quart / Hypercorn microservice which runs in a conda environment configured with an environment.yml file. The base image is continuumio/miniconda3.

It took a lot of hacks to get this launching because of conda init issues etc.

Is there a cleaner way to get a conda environment installed and activated within Docker without having to resort to conda run commands and override the default SHELL commands?

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

COPY . /api/

WORKDIR /api/src

# See this tutorial for details https://pythonspeed.com/articles/activate-conda-dockerfile/
RUN conda env create -f /api/conda_environment_production.yml
SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "ms-amazing-environment", "/bin/bash", "-c"]
ENTRYPOINT ["conda", "run", "--no-capture-output", "-n", "ms-amazing-environment", "hypercorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:5000", "QuartAPI:app"]

EXPOSE 5000
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative approach is described [here](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/activate-conda-dockerfile/).

Basically you can activate conda environment within bash script and run you commands there.

`entrypoint.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash --login
# The --login ensures the bash configuration is loaded,

# Temporarily disable strict mode and activate conda:
set +euo pipefail
conda activate ms-amazing-environment
# enable strict mode:
set -euo pipefail

# exec the final command:
exec hypercorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 QuartAPI:app
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

COPY . /api/

WORKDIR /api/src

# See this tutorial for details https://pythonspeed.com/articles/activate-conda-dockerfile/
RUN conda env create -f /api/conda_environment_production.yml

# The code to run when container is started:
COPY entrypoint.sh ./
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 5000
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks!